# How to change primary domain for an application

Tags: subdomain, appdomain

Presently, we host our java/j2ee web application with a third party hosting company.
Application URL is like abc-xyz.com
This primary domain abc-xyz.com is going to expire in couple of months. Client doesn't want to use this domain anymore and wants to register completely a new domain. In order to accomodate primary domain change, what needs to be done? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad subject.

If your client is willing to pay for the service why not just let the hosting company move the contents to the new domain.  As far as what to do with the web application it really depends on where and how paths have been declared.

Some developers use static paths.  I have seen some sites store the domain name in a text file and reference it through out the site, so a path would look like this where
    `x='new domain name'`
    `<img src="x/images/yourpic.png">`

However using static paths can be very frustrating.  It is better to use relative paths in respect to the root of the domain.  So the above would look like this instead: 
    `<img src="../images/yourpic.png">`

Another thing to consider are the paths to the datasources.  If you are running something like cold fusion the datasource is set in the cold fusion administrator so moving a site can be as simple as moving the tables and pages then ensuring that the datasources are set correctly.  In php developers typically will set a connect function for all database connections in one file.

This may or may not answer your question but the bottom line is that it really depends on how the site is structured and what type of platform is being used.

Comment: Thanks Mark. What if I keep everything (internal infrastructure configurations) as it is so that when I type the new url in the browser somehow just redirect it to abc-xyz.com. Any issues with this approach?